# How to get the duration of mp3 file without playing or storing them

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am building a wp8 app which could play poems line by line displayed in listbox.

Say I have 20 lines of Poems showing as 20 items in listbox. I have 20 mp3 files (one for each line), I used BackgroundAudioPlayer to play individual files and select each item (poem) in listbox. During playback of these mp3 files, there were delays of 1-3 seconds, so I found the full version of these mp3 files (20 files merged into one), reading poems line by line.

I am playing this mp3 file using BackgroundAudioPlayer. Playing as one file, I cannot select each item in listbox as I don't know the line number by playing one mp3 file.

Now what I want is to store the duration of 20 files in seconds, without storing and playing. The files are located in a link (http:123.com/1.mp3, /2.mp3, ...)

I used AudioTrack with absolute path and then used duration property, but it always returns zero. How can I get the duration of an mp3 file without playing them?

**Edited:** 
In the background Agent I did below:

```
protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
{
switch (playState)
{
case PlayState.TrackReady:
TrackDuration tr = DataSource.Connection.Table<TrackDuration>().SingleOrDefault();
if (tr.IsGetTrackDuration)
{
if (player.Track != null)
{
player.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(player.Track.Duration.TotalSeconds);
Recitation r = DataSource.Connection.Query<Recitation>("select * from Recitation where ID = " + player.Track.Title).SingleOrDefault();
r.AyaDuration = player.Track.Duration.TotalSeconds;
DataSource.saveRecitionDownloaded(r);
PlayNextTrack(player);
}
}
break;
}
NotifyComplete();
}

protected override void OnUserAction(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, UserAction action, object param)
{
switch (action)
{
case UserAction.Play:
   PlayTrack(player);
break;
case UserAction.Seek:
if (null!=player.Track)
player.Position = (TimeSpan)param;
break;
}
NotifyComplete();
}

private void PlayNextTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
{
 if (++currentTrackNumber >= audioTrack.Count)
   return;
 PlayTrack(player);
}

private void PlayTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
{
//If No Track then load Track
 if (audioTrack.Count == 0)
 {
     //Load Tracks and Add them into Track Play List
 }
if ((player.Track == null) || (player.Track.Title != audioTrack[currentTrackNumber].Title))
    player.Track = audioTrack[currentTrackNumber];

if ((player.Track != null) && (player.PlayerState != PlayState.Playing))
    player.Play();
}
```

The question is It plays some of the files which I don't want. (tr.IsGetTrackDuration) is always true, but I don't know why it plays some?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to store (download) each individual file? You could then delete each track after playback is completed, if storage space is an issue.

Comment: I don't know if you understand my situation, instead of downloading 20 mp3 files I like to download only 1 file. I would get the duration from 20 files and highlight each line when reaching specific position. I would timer to manage this.

Comment: No, I understand it perfectly. What I was asking is why you're against downloading each file individually? This is the only way you'll be able to read the track length.

Comment: You mean, I download 20 files, store them, get the duration and then delete it?,is it possible to get duration without playing? and finally download the single mp3 file.

Comment: It is a tricky situation, isn't it? I would personally download the individual files, since I'm guessing they aren't very big. I would then serialize a List<string> of the track Uri's. When one track is completed, you would then fetch the next Uri from the list and play it.

Comment: And just to be clear, when you first tried playing the individual files were they downloaded? Or were you streaming them? If you were streaming, that would account for the 1 - 3 second delay. Download would likely eliminate the problem.

Comment: I downloaded all mp3 files (20) and I added them into playlist (Audio Track list) and used TrackEnded PlayState to point to next track in the list just the same as (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx). This caused delay of 1-3 seconds on playing each track, That's why I find out the full mp3 in one file. (I was playing files locally)

Answer (score 1):

[MusicProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties.aspx) class has a property for the duration

```
 MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
 outputText.AppendLine("Duration: " + musicProperties.Duration);
```

Comment: This will not work, as the files are located on a remote server.

Comment: Unfortunately (for now) it won't work as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.storage.storagefile.properties.aspx says - Windows Phone 8 This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called.

Comment: And because it would require storing the mp3s, which the OP doesn't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a thought here. Under the AudioPlayer class, there is a TrackReady event that is set by default to play the track. Instead of playing by default, set a bool to true if you're simply wanting to obtain the duration, and false if you actually wish to play a track (when you're wanting to play the full mp3).

The bool value would have to be set in the main app before the track is set, and then read in the AudioPlayer each time the OnPlayStateChanged is called.

```
protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
{
    //read GettingDuration value here

    try
    {
        switch (playState)
        {
            case PlayState.TrackReady:
                if (GettingDuration)
                {
                //store duration somehow and get the next track in line
                }
                else
                {
                    player.Play();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, I don't want to play mp3 files, it stores the duration, but it plays some of my audio track.